# No logro hacer conexion a BD MYSQL Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

tengo una clase conexion, en la cual mando a llamar los atributos desde un archivo de propiedades, los cuales son una URL, USER y PASS, los cuales estoy cargando de manera adecuada porque me estoy asegurando de leer un archivo de propiedades, y si lo hago muy bien...luego tengo una clase lineaTransaccion con la cual quiero hacer la conexion a mi BD y hacer un UPDATE a unas tablas, la cuestion es que no logro hacer la conexion a la BD MySQL... no sé donde podria tener el error...

```
package com.ba.util;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.ba.util.Constantes;

public class Conexion {

    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class);
    static Connection conexion = null;
    
    
    public static Connection getConexion() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        String URL = "";
        String USER = "";
        String PASS = "";

        try {
            
            URL  = UtilProperties.prop.getProperty(Constantes.DBCORP_URL);
            USER = UtilProperties.prop.getProperty(Constantes.DBCORP_USERNAME);
            PASS = UtilProperties.prop.getProperty(Constantes.DBCORP_PASSWORD);
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Conexion Fallida..!!", e);
            closeCon();
        }

        return conexion;
    }

    public static void closeCon() {
        try {
            conexion.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

y desde donde quiero hacer la conexion es de esta clase...

```
package com.ba.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



public class LineaTransaccionDB {
    static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LineaTransaccionDB.class.getName());
    
    public static void insertTramaRSP(String message, byte[] correlation, String idTransaccion, String dbcorp_url, String dbcorp_username, String dbcorp_password){
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        
        LOG.info("[MESSAGE]: "+message);
        LOG.info("[CORRELATION]: "+correlation);
        LOG.info("[DBCORP_URL ]: "+dbcorp_url);
        LOG.info("[ID TRANSACCION]"+idTransaccion);
        try {
            **con = Conexion.getConexion();**
            String sql = "UPDATE basededatos.tablabasededatos set tramaSalida = ? where transaccion = ?";
            pstm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            LOG.info("Statement Creado");
            pstm.setString(1, message);
            pstm.setString(2, idTransaccion);
            if(pstm.executeUpdate()>0) {
                LOG.info("**[TRAMA  INSERTADA]**");
            }else {
                pstm.close();
            }
            
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error Insert[" + e.getMessage() + "]");          
            
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pstm.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                LOG.error("Error cerrando conexion a BD: " + e2.getMessage());
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

en mi archivo de Logs solo solo me imprime a está parte:

```
LOG.info("[MESSAGE]: "+message);
LOG.info("[CORRELATION]: "+correlation);
LOG.info("[DBCORP_URL ]: "+dbcorp_url);
LOG.info("[ID TRANSACCION]"+idTransaccion);
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Es rarísimo que tu código no imprima el `LOG.info("Statement Creado");` siendo que está justo abajo de la salida que muestras.

Comment: Y porque los asteriscos en * *con = Conexion.getConexion();* *?

Comment: @TomuRain ese es el problema, no esta haciendo la conexion a la BD, he hecho otra impresion de logs y llego hasta acá...    try {
      LOG.info("Preparando Conexion");
      con = Conexion.getConexion();

Comment: @JFrame StackOverflow me lo agrego al querer poner en negrita esa parte, en mi codigo esta sin los **

Answer (score -1):

Es posible que una de estas dos causas no hace posible la ejecución de tu proyecto :

- asegúrate que existe el jar que contenga el driver de MYSQL en el classPath de tu proyecto.
- para algunos drives JDBC debes crear una instancia del driver de esta manera : intentan cambiando `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); por    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`

referencia : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html